# How can I merge 3 commands and execute them

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm try to run a script that figures out the paths based on the hostname:
e.g. if hostname returns `computer1` I would like to run `path/to/Computer1.py` (where path/to is a path that will always be the same).

The path part I figured I could use a variable to store it, then recall and concatenate later.
I looked up now to convert a string to title case and this seems to work:

```
echo "computer1.py" | awk '{printf("%s%s\n",toupper(substr($0,1,1)),substr($0,2))}'
```

I'm fairly new to bash and currently I'm getting stuck on how I should concatenate these components ( path to script, script name based on `hostname`) and execute them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash version 4 introduced built-in case-modification operators `^` and `,` operators, making it possible to avoid external programs like awk for such simple string manipulations if you have a recent version of the bash shell. In particular, if

```
name=$(hostname)
```

and

```
path="path/to/"
```

then

```
"${path}${name^}"
```

should concatenate the strings, with the first letter of `name` upper-cased. See the `Parameter Expansion` section of the bash manual page `man bash`.

Comment: That is very helpful(+1). Unfortunately I haven't managed to get the upper-cased part working. I get ```bad substitution```. For example ``` n='computer1'``` then calling ```${n^}``` prints ```bad substitution```. What am I missing ? Thank you

Comment: For now I did something like this: ```$('/path/to/'$(hostname | awk '{printf("%s%s.py",toupper(substr($0,1,1)),substr($0,2))}'))``` and this worked, but doesn't look as elegant as what you're proposing. Looking forward to learn how to use that correctly

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza what is your platform and bash version (`bash --version`)? IIRC the built-in toupper (`^`) and tolower (`,`) operators were introduced in Bash 4 - perhaps your shell doesn't have them. BTW don't feel obligated to accept an answer if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I tested initially on osx running ```GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin14)```, however script is intended to un on a Raspberry PI 2 running raspian. I don't have access to one right now, so can't provide the bash version at the moment. It looks like your answer should've worked and it looks elegant which is why I accepted it. You are right, but perhaps just mention your solution runs on Bash 4 which might help people looking at your answer in the future (and skipping your comments)